# Array duplicate removal program in PErl

Tags: perl

I am new to programming and i am trying the c logic to implement in Perl for the array duplicate removal.

But i am not getting required output.Can some please give pointer where did i go wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

@x = (2,2,3,1);
$n = 3;
for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
    for ($j=$i+1;$j<$n;$j++) {
        if ($x[$i]=$x[$j]) {
            for ($k=$j;$k<$n;$k++)
            {
                print " pip";
                $x[$k] = $x[$k+1];
                print "k = $x[$k] ,j = $x[$j]\n";
                $n--;
            }
        } else {
            $j++;
        }
    }
}
print @x;
```

Comment: Please don't tag arbitrary languages that your question has nothing to do with. -Python.

Comment: `if ($x[$i]=$x[$j]) {` - Are you sure you want to assign here?

Answer (score 4):

Your logic looks horrendous, but I do spot that you have made a rookie mistake, which may explain your program failing:

```
if ($x[$i] = $x[$j]) {
```

Here you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the numerical equality operator `==`. The assignment will, of course, assign the right hand parameter to the left hand parameter, which overwrites your array and corrupts your input.

As a side note, the return value of this statement is `$x[$j]`, which may or may not be a true value, depending on your data. (for numerical data, `0` and undef will be false, all other true)

**Edit:**

It seems that this is not all that is wrong with your program, because it still fails. Trying to debug it does not seem like a good use of time, when deduping is so easily done in Perl, and this is a horrible way of doing it (sorry, but it is). Look at the other answers for how it is done with a hash -- make use of the fact that hash keys are unique.

This is how the dedupe function `uniq` is implemented in [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils):

```
sub uniq (@) {
    my %seen = ();
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

Quite simple, isn't it? Just return the keys which are `not` seen before.

Answer (score 0):

try using a hash for this:

```
my %h;
for my $i (@x) {
  $h{$i}++
}
@x = (keys %h);
```

this puts each value of `@x` into `%h` as the key and has the number of occurences of the element as the value in %h. if you just retrieve the keys `(keys %h)`, you will have the distinct elements of `@x`, which you can then put back into `@x`.

Answer (score 0):

it does not want to change the contents when you are referring to an element of an array is good.

```
@x = (2,2,3,1);
@hash { @x } = 0; 
@x = keys %hash;
print @x;
```

---

```
#use Array::Uniq from CPAN
use Array::Uniq;
@x = (2,2,3,1);
@x = uniq @x; #or uniq sort @x;
print @x; # result:231
```

Comment: Thanks all of you time for valuable feedback.